# Cannot use import statement outside a module in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, import, es6-modules

I tried to import a function from `utils.js` in `index.js` when I refresh the page it says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at index.mjs:1:1)
```

index.js

```js
import { waitForElement } from "./utils.js"

console.log(waitForElement("body", 2000))
```

manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "Name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "description",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "host_permissions": ["https://*.themoviedb.org/movie/*", "https://*.themoviedb.org/tv/*", "https://*.imdb.com/title/*"],
    "icons": {
        "16": "assets/icon/icon-16.png",
        "24": "assets/icon/icon-24.png",
        "32": "assets/icon/icon-32.png",
        "48": "assets/icon/icon-48.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "src/background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://*.themoviedb.org/*", "https://*.imdb.com/*"],
            "js": ["src/index.js"]
        }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Name"
    }
}
```